# Possible to change names/serialization output in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

So, I have a form that I'm submitting via JQuery/Ajax
HTML:

```
<form id="emailsignup" method="post">
<p><input name="contactfirst_name" placeholder="Your First Name" type="text"> 
<input name="contactemail” placeholder="youremail@address.com" type="text"> 
<button class="btn btn-success btn-large">Sign Me Up</button>
<input name="action" value="ext_addcontact" type="hidden">
<input name="selectedgroupname" value="Website Opt-Ins" type="hidden">
<input name="groupownerid" value="[p:pid]" type="hidden">
<input name="redirect" value="path/to/success.html" type="hidden"> 
<input name="redirect_error" value="path/to/failure.html" type="hidden">
```

And then passing it through via Javascript
JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$.post("path/to/index.php", $(".emailsignup").serialize());
});
});
</script>
```

OK, so here's where it gets fun. I need to change the way the format in which the data is serialized, because the server is looking for <strike>this output:</strike>

<strike>contact%5Bfirst_name%5D=data&contact%5Bemail%5D=data&etc=data</strike>

EDIT: The server is looking for the words after contact to be in square brackets
(IE: I need to find a way, when serializing, to input the square brackets or their character code equivalents to turn contactfirst_name into contact[first_name] and contactemail into contact[email]) - however, I cannot just rename the names contact[first_name] and contact[email]. This is a form hosted on a marketing automation platform, and [first_name] and [email] are system variables, which means that they would get converted on page load (why use the same syntax for both I don't know... beyond me).

So, I guess I'm trying to use Javascript to insert the square brackets in after serializing, but without ever actually spelling out the full name.

<strike>Changing the NAMES on the form are not an option, as using the unencoded characters (ie: contact[first_name], contact[email]) trigger variables in the platform that the form is hosted on. For the same reason, changing the php file I'm posting to is not an option, as it's a closed platform.</strike>

Is there any way to do this with, say, beforesubmit? If so, where do I insert it into my script and what arguments am I passing through?

In terms of comfort level here, I cobbled this script together from an example I found on W3Schools and another website - I'm very much a novice at Jquery and Javascript in general aside from replacing classes/id's where there are placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel like an idiot - the issue was that the data was being posted in a serialize fashion. I was able to achieve what I needed by setting ID's to each field and then renaming the names through .setAttribute. I'm sure this is super bulky and could be much more simple/elegant, but hey, I'm learning:

```
function quoteRequest() {
var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
var lName = document.getElementById("lname");
var contactEmail = document.getElementById("email");
var productQty = document.getElementById("qty");
var additionalInfo = document.getElementById("additionalinfo");
var product = document.getElementById("product");
var productnum = document.getElementById("productnum");
fName.setAttribute('name', 'contact\[first_name\]');
lName.setAttribute('name', 'contact\[last_name\]');
contactEmail.setAttribute('name', 'contact\[email\]');
productQty.setAttribute('name', 'contact\[qty\]');
product.setAttribute('name', 'contact\[product\]');
productnum.setAttribute('name', 'contact\[productnum\]');
document.getElementById("quoteform").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save serealized data to local var. Then replace keys with a one you need.

```
var serialized;

serialized = $(".emailsignup").serialize();
serialized = serialized.replace(/contact([^=]+)/, 'contact[$1]');
serialized = encodeURIComponent(serialized);

$.post("path/to/index.php", serialized);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you cannot change the name attributes of the form fields (e.g. name="contactfirst_name" to name="contact[first_name]").

So if you have to do it on submit, you could put the serialized post data into a variable and then do some searching/replacing to transform it to the way you want.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("button").on('click', function () {
        var formData = $('.emailsignup').serialize();

        formData = formData.replace(/contactfirst_name/, 'contact%5Bfirst_name%5D');
        // do more replacing for the other fields like the above...
        $.post("path/to/index.php", formData, function () {
            // do stuff
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct and not correct. I CAN edit the name attributes - however, I cannot actually use the literal names (contact[first_name], contact[email]) - anything encapsulated in square brackets, to the system, looks like a variable, so on load it replaces that text with the variable encoded in the system. Apparently it doesn't like my URI-encoded characters. I'm looking into the formData.replace function to see if there's a different way I can do this to re-insert the square brackets vs /contactfirst_name/, 'contact[first_name]', as that translates on page load to 'contactValued Customer'.

Comment: OK - so I took this format that you gave me and was able to successfully use the formData.replace function to add back in my square brackets, and it is showing up correctly (hooray) on page load. however, it's still failing, and I don't have a way of getting the specific error back from the server to see where I went wrong. Is it possible to serialize after performing the formData.replaces? I don't see why it would make a difference...]