# How to remove name prefix on partial view elements on ajax post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this on my partial view

```
 @Html.Partial("_ChampDestination", Model.MultiplePaths, new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "MultiplePaths" } })
```

This is necessary for the binding to be done on the form with the list in the controller action. This adds MultiplePaths as a prefix.

But I want to make Ajax calls before the whole form post which posts a `list<Destination>` but with the prefix added it doesn't do the binding well.

Is there a way to manually remove the prefix easily via jquery, or i need to loop through all the inputs and remove the prefix from the name manually.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the ViewDataDictionary? = simply using  @Html.Partial("_ChampDestination", Model.MultiplePaths)

Comment: that will work for the ajax call, but fail my form post since the binding of the whole model needs the prefix

Comment: I see. In that case, you might need to change the serialized form data before posting it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066942/possible-to-change-names-serialization-output-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this the answer is to manually remove the prefix from the model, don't know if it might cause some security issues.

```
var model = $("#MultiplePaths:input").serialize();
model = model.replace(/MultiplePaths%5B/, '%5B');
```